# Is there a simpler way to do arithmetic in PSTricks?

Tags: pstricks, calculations

I want to animate PSTricks diagram, so looping is intensively used. I have 3 global variables `\START`, `\STOP`, `\DELTA` that should be declared in the preamble. The remaining variables in the body will make use of these 3 global variables.

The looping macro `\multido` needs an integer that represents how many times it must repeat the given job. Unfortunately, this value is not given explicitly but It can be obtained from a simple formula `\STOP-\START` divided by `\DELTA`. I need a simple way to find this number in integer rather than in floating point number.

Finding `\INITIAL` variable by taking advantage of `\dimexpr` and `\strip@pt` is also not so natural I think.

The following coding flow looks too complicated, I need more fluid approach.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{multido}

\newcommand\START{-1}
\newcommand\STOP{1}
\newcommand\DELTA{0.01}


% to do division only, but the result in floating point
\pstFPdiv\TempTimes
{
        \the
        \dimexpr
        \STOP pt
        -\START pt
        \relax
}
{\DELTA}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\INITIAL
{
        \strip@pt
        \dimexpr
        \START pt
        +\DELTA pt
        \relax
}

% to make it an integer
\newcommand\TIMES
{
        \strip@pt
        \dimexpr
        \TempTimes pt
        \relax
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\multido
{
        \nx=\START+\DELTA,
        \ny=\INITIAL+\DELTA
}
{\TIMES}
{
    (\nx,\ny)\endgraf
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps add a little more context, or even comment your code. What is it that you're after? Merely reproducing your output with different/simpler code is possible.

Comment: Your division is a subtraction. Putting everything on a line of its own makes it hard to read.

Comment: @Werner: She only wants a very simple for-loop. But the code is awful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution without loading `fp`. If you do not need exactly two digits then you do not need `\StripDecimals`

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{pst-func,multido}
\def\StripDecimals#1{\expandafter\SD#10!}
\def\SD#1.#2#3#4!{%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax#1.\else#1.#2#3\fi}

\newcommand\START{-1.00}
\newcommand\STOP{1.00}
\newcommand\DELTA{0.01}

\pstFPsub\Temp\STOP\START 
\pstFPDiv\TIMES\Temp\DELTA
\pstFPadd\Temp\START\DELTA
\pstFPstripZeros\Temp\INITIAL

\begin{document}

\multido{\rx=\START+\DELTA,
         \ry=\INITIAL+\DELTA}{\TIMES}
  {(\StripDecimals{\rx0},\StripDecimals{\ry0})\endgraf}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not particularly familiar with PStricks' floating point operations (via `pst-func`), so my preference is to use the [`fp` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fp).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}%

\newcommand\START{-1}
\newcommand\STOP{1}
\newcommand\DELTA{0.01}
\FPupn\INITIAL{\START{} \DELTA{} add 2 trunc}% floating point truncation
\FPupn\TIMES{\STOP{} \START{} sub \DELTA{} div 0 trunc}% integer truncation

\begin{document}
\multido
{
  \nx=\START+\DELTA,
  \ny=\INITIAL+\DELTA
}
{\TIMES}
{
  (\nx,\ny)\endgraf
}
\end{document}
```

In performing calculations that require [rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding)  you can use `n round` where `n` denotes the number of digits after the decimal.

Comment: I think infix syntax (by `\FPeval`) is preferred as a 'simpler way'.

Comment: @Leo: True. I am familiar with using [RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) since PStricks requires this in its postscript node computations: `\pnode(!ps){...}`, and perhaps the OP is as well. But I agree - it is easier to read.

Comment: @Werner: I can parse RPN. :-)

Comment: @Werner: `\pnode(* arithmetic){...}` is also possible

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't add units after pure numeric values.
2. `fp` package provides full ability to do complex arithmetic calculations.

The code is in fact not PSTricks related:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{multido}

\newcommand\START{-1}
\newcommand\STOP{1}
\newcommand\DELTA{0.01}
\FPeval\INITIAL{round((START + DELTA):2)}
\FPeval\TIMES{round((STOP-START)/DELTA:0)}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\multido{\nx=\START+\DELTA, \ny=\INITIAL+\DELTA}{\TIMES}
{
  (\nx,\ny)\endgraf
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I apologize to all but I would like to resurrect this old thread. I was a bit surprised to see answers to original question focusing on LaTeX's `fp` package. There are good reasons TeX can not do floating point arithmetics but PostScript is definitely capable of doing it.

http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb23-3-4/tb75beccreal.pdf

My understanding of `pstricks` is that is a user friendly way to get raw PostScript code into TeX file (Note, I am just a very low level `pstricks` user). Here is one not so user friendly way to do the same.

The following line inputs the picture into TeX code with horizontal offset of 72 and a vertical offset of -150. The reason for verbose horizontal and vertical output is that command special puts the picture right after the text in the box of default size 0.

```
\special{psfile=my_PostScript_file.ps hoffset=72 voffset=-150 hscale=90 
vscale=90}
\bye
```

The `my_PostScript_file.ps` is of course programmed by hand. For example as

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0 EPSF-2.0
%%Title: tata.fig
%%Creator: Predrag
%%CreationDate: Sun Dec 25 23:29:18 2011
%%For: predrag@oko.bagdala2.net (Predrag Punosevac)
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 110 101
%Magnification: 1.0000
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog
%%EndProlog
/Times_Roman findfont
15 scalefont

setfont
50 50 moveto
(Some text)show
newpath
5 5 moveto
10 45 lineto
stroke
showpage
%EOF
```

It is now clear that it would be "easy" to do any animation involving floating point arithmetics by programming in raw PostScript.