# Fractals with LaTeX

Tags: fractals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate Mandelbrot images using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39474/generate-mandelbrot-images-using-tikz)

Is there a professional package to plot the most important fractals with LaTeX?

I searched in internet, but none of the result is sufficiently satisfactory.

Comment: Can you include the requirements to be satisfactory?

Comment: a possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39474/9467

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the package `pst-fractal` based on the powerful `pstricks`. It helps one draw Sierpinski triangles, Julia sets, Mandelbrot sets, phyllotaxes, ferns, Koch flakes, Apollonius circles and trees.

Comment: This seems to be a good package I didn't sow! ; )